# "Visit link" problems

Tags: bug, status-completed

The "visit parent" and "visit meta" send me to http://stackexchange.com instead of stats.exchange or meta.stats.stackexchange

Comment: "Visit meta" has now disappeared. Presumably the "Visit parent" will go soon too. There are new links to meta and parent on the top right instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should now see a "Stack Exchange" logo instead of the previous parent/meta icon. If not, hit Ctrl-F5.

The parent/meta links are now located in the main title bar.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason behind the UI change?  The previous position was far more prominent befitting its likely frequency of use whereas the new position is much less conspicuous.